# Only pull certain parts of objects through GET request

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

On my web app's homepage I fire off a GET request to my API in order to pull a current list of Stadiums in my database. I need certain parts of each Stadium object (name, city, state, prim_hex, sec_hex, active). The problem is that these Stadium objects also contain a "photos" array with tens of thousands of 'photo' objects. Since my get request pulls back all Stadium objects my homepage takes 5-10 seconds to load (due to the large "photos" arrays).

My relevant code is below. How would I go about altering my GET request to only pull back the pieces I need (in other words, do not pull in "photos" arrays on homepage load)?

Example Stadium object:

```
{
"_id": {
    "$oid": "54148f29e4b01927d54d26bc"
},
"name": "High Point Solutions Stadium",
"division": "East",
"team": "Rutgers Scarlet Knights",
"city": "Piscataway",
"city_norm": "Piscataway",
"state": "NJ",
"loc": [
    -74.465573,
    40.513676
],
"loc_id": 300149,
"prim_hex": "#d21034",
"sec_hex": "#000000",
"logo": "rutgers",
"active": false,
"photos": [...]
}
```

Current GET code in 'routes.js' on my nodejs server:

```
// get all stadia
app.get('/api/stadia', function(req, res) {

    // use mongoose to get all stadia in the database
    Stadium.find(function(err, stadia) {

        // if there is an error retrieving, send the error. nothing after res.send(err) will execute
        if (err)
            res.send(err)

        res.jsonp(stadia); // return all stadia in JSON format
    });
});
```

I believe the `res.jsonp(stadia)` code is what needs to be altered, but am not sure how to properly alter it to only pull certain pieces of each Stadium object.

Comment: You need to refer to your API documentation. There may be a way to pass parameters to the url, or there may be a different url for doing what you want. Or it may not support such a request. Once you learn how to tell the API to only retrieve the data you want, then you can start figuring out how to modify the url `'api/stadia'` in your code.

Comment: Thanks @LeeJenkins. That's the thing, there is no API documentation. This is my API. I'm trying to figure out how to customize my GET route for /stadia to only return certain pieces of each Stadium object.

Comment: @MattDionis He is referring to the [Mongoose API documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html)

Comment: @MattDionis sorry I wasn't paying close enough attention. Now I see what you're asking. I'll post a possible solution in a few minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To hard code it:

```
Stadium.find({}, "-photos", function (err, stadia) {
    // do stuff
});
```

OR (the method I more frequently use):

```
var query = Stadium.find();
query.select("-photos");
query.exec(function (err, stadia) {
    // do stuff
});
```

The second form allows you to construct and add queries without having one large object to stick in the `Model.find()`

Take a look at [the API docs for Model.find](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find) and [query.select](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-select)

Answer (score 1):

First I would re-define the schema for the data response for GET /api/stadia. Instead of providing an array of photos in the data structure, I would only provide an array of unique IDs for the photos. I assume the photos can be referenced individually by some kind of unique identifier.

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "54148f29e4b01927d54d26bc"
    },
    ... other properties ...
    "active": false,
    "photoIDs": [ "ID-12345", "ID-67890" ]
}
```

Then I would add a distinct url for requesting the photos.

```
app.get('/api/stadia/photo/:photoID', function(req, res) {
    var photoID = req.param( "photoID" );
    // now get that one photo from mongodb and return it
    ...
});
```

Or, if you prefer the simpler interface of one GET request for all photos, you just make a separate URL for that:

```
app.get('/api/stadia/photos', function(req, res) {
    // respond with the array of all the photos
    ...
});
```